# How to filter users by last_name?

Tags: users

How can I implement functions.php as a last name filter option? Note that a search for users on the Wordpress admin panel page - users.php is not possible to filter users by the last name, how can you include this filter? Does anyone share any snippets for this?

I tried this but it doesn't work.

```
//search usertable
$wp_user_query = new WP_User_Query(
  array(
    'search' => "*{$str}*",
    'search_columns' => array(
    'user_login',
    'user_nicename',
    'user_email',
  ),

) );
 $users = $wp_user_query->get_results();

//search usermeta
 $wp_user_query2 = new WP_User_Query(
  array(
    'meta_query' => array(
    'relation' => 'OR',
      array(
        'key' => 'first_name',
        'value' => $str,
        'compare' => 'LIKE'
      ),
    array(
        'key' => 'last_name',
        'value' => $str,
        'compare' => 'LIKE'
      )
    )
  )
 );

$users2 = $wp_user_query2->get_results();

$totalusers_dup = array_merge($users,$users2);

$totalusers = array_unique($totalusers_dup, SORT_REGULAR);
```

Comment: Have you tried hooking your snippet to some late running hook to see if your query works in general? If that works, you will want to intercept the query for the users list table. There are quite some examples on how to do this on this site. The hook you might  need should be `'pre_user_query'`.